# Bootstrap carousel not working in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get Bootstraps carousel to work with rails... what am I missing?

1.) I downloaded a custom version of bootstrap with the carousel component.
2.) Placed it in my assets/js and required the file in application.js
3.) Initialized the carousel by:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel()
});
```

4.) Put my html markup:

```
<section class="wrapper row">
  <article class="slider">
        <!--  Carousel - consult the Twitter Bootstrap docs at 
      http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel -->
<div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide"><!-- class of slide for animation -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <p>Caption text here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
  <!--  Next and Previous controls below
        href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
  </article>
</section>
```

It's not working! Any ideas?

Comment: `$('.carousel').carousel();` <--- semicolon

Comment: still not working... :(

Comment: Bootstrap js files are being loaded correctly...

Comment: Not working meaning not appearing or not sliding?

Comment: I couldn't make it work, I changed to rs_slide and it worked out of the box. **** bootstrap.